# Perform simple calculations in javascript within CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a script within CSS code in order to calculate a subtotal. Unfortunately, the JSON/XML feed does not give me the subtotal I'm looking for.

```
<MetaData>
<labor currency="CAD">0</labor>
<parts currency="CAD">1234</parts>
<discount currency="CAD">246.8</discount>
<tax currency="CAD">147.8332</tax>
<total currency="CAD">1135.0332</total>
</MetaData>
```

I want to calculate PARTS-DISCOUNT and need to parse the content of the MetaData into floats to make the calculation and then convert it to string to display it.

```
<script>

var subtotalbeforediscount = parseFloat(Workorder.MetaData.parts, 10);
var discounttotal = parseFloat(Workorder.MetaData.discount, 10);
var subtotalfinal = subtotalbeforediscount - discounttotal;
var subtotalfinaltxt = subtotalfinal.toString();

</script>
```

Of course, this script does not work because the MetaData is not parsed, only the letters are parsed.

How can I make such calculation before displaying it?

Here is the CSS section where I just want to display the result of the calculation:

```
              <tr>

                    <td>Sub-total final</td>

                    <td id="subtotalfinal" class="amount">

                        {{subtotalfinaltxt|money}}

                    </td>

                </tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] - click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54463542/edit) and then the `[<>]` snippet editor to show what you mean. I see no CSS here

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS Section" - I see HTML and some templating. No CSS. Can you tell us what templating you use? Smarty or something

Comment: As part of a commercial software (Lightspeed Retail), I can include a script that is processed. This script is based on HTML and CSS (and probably javascript). I just showed-up the relevant sections of the code/script. The MetaData is accessible by the script when it's processed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to ask LightSpeedHQ for support - if no support, then JavaScript/jQuery can do this:

```js
var WorkorderString = `<MetaData>
<labor currency="CAD">0</labor>
<parts currency="CAD">1234</parts>
<discount currency="CAD">246.8</discount>
<tax currency="CAD">147.8332</tax>
<total currency="CAD">1135.0332</total>
</MetaData>`

var oParser = new DOMParser();
var $Workorder = $(oParser.parseFromString(WorkorderString, "application/xml")).find("MetaData");
var subtotalbeforediscount = parseFloat($Workorder.find("parts").text(), 10);
var discounttotal = parseFloat($Workorder.find("discount").text(), 10);
var subtotalfinal = (subtotalbeforediscount - discounttotal).toFixed(2);
var subtotalfinaltxt = subtotalfinal.toString();
$("#subtotalfinal").text(subtotalfinaltxt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub-total final</td>
    <td id="subtotalfinal" class="amount">
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I placed a call at LS Support, waiting for an answer but I doubt they will propose a solution. The tricky part here is that the MetaData is not part of the script. I just included the data to demonstrate what is available. I can call the MetaData in the script or parse it but I can't parse it like in your example.

Comment: If it’s returned in an Ajax call you can parse it

Comment: The part that I don't understand is that when the whole HTML/CSS script is executed/call, the metadata values are available in memory, so why parsing it in javascript if in the instance, I can print the values without parsing them?

Comment: I have no idea since I do not know how your code runs

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Lightspeed was kind enough to spend some time to find the solution.

Here is the final section of the script that calculate the field. There are more conditions in this script but basically, they were able to use the metadata and perform a calculation.

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const discount = document.querySelector('#totalsDiscountsValue');
    if (discount) {
        const subtotal = document.querySelector('#totalsPartsValue');
        const subTotalWDiscount = Number(subtotal.innerText.replace(/\$/g, "")) +
            Number(discount.innerText.replace(/\$/g, ""));
        const row = discount.parentElement;
        row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<tr>
<td>Sous-total avec Réductions</td>
<td>${subTotalWDiscount}</td>
</tr>`);
    }
})



</script>
```

Hope that could help someone else.